Can't set the number format of cells in a typed column
The currency formats are not updating in the following ranges:

Expenses!C3:C'
Income !C3:C'
Transfer !D3:D'
Wallets !D3:D'

These ranges are formatted as Google Sheets tables. Other ranges are working properly, except for these table-formatted ranges.
Its showing error

Exception: You can't set the number format of cells in a typed column.

function updateCurrencyFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var customizationsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Customizations ❤️');
  var currencySymbol = customizationsSheet.getRange('B14').getValue();

  // Construct the currency format string using the currency symbol from B14
  var currencyFormat = currencySymbol + '#,##0.00_);[Red](' + currencySymbol + '#,##0.00)';

  var rangesToUpdate = [
    'Computations!D2:H',
    'Computations!M3:Q',
    'Computations!T2:T',
    'Computations!X2:X',
    'Dashboard !A11',
    'Dashboard !A15',
    'Dashboard !A18',
    'Dashboard !D18'
  ];

  var dynamicRanges = [
    'Dashboard !B23',
    'Dashboard !F23',
    'Dashboard !N23',
    'Dashboard !S23',
    'Dashboard !W23',
    'Expenses!C3:C',
    'Income !C3:C',
    'Transfer !D3:D',
    'Wallets !D3:D'
  ];

  // Update static ranges
  rangesToUpdate.forEach(function(rangeAddress) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(rangeAddress.split('!')[0]);
    var range = sheet.getRange(rangeAddress.split('!')[1]);
    range.setNumberFormat(currencyFormat);
  });

  // Update dynamic ranges
  dynamicRanges.forEach(function(rangeAddress) {
    var sheetName = rangeAddress.split('!')[0];
    var startCell = rangeAddress.split('!')[1];
    var column = startCell.charAt(0);
    var startRow = parseInt(startCell.substring(1));

    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    if (lastRow >= startRow) {
      var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, column.charCodeAt(0) - 'A'.charCodeAt(0) + 1, lastRow - startRow + 1);
      range.setNumberFormat(currencyFormat);
    }
  });
}

Im trying to change the currency format.

Hi Welcome ! Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

What is the value for currencySymbol?

What is your Locale?

the currency symbol in cell B14 is $

One currency symbol that happens to be in the spreadsheet doesn't tell much about the locale of the spreadsheet. Please specify the locale you've set in File > Settings > Locale.

it's United States<3

Is it possible to  change the currency format in that typed column manually  using the user interface?

With respect, Kenneth, we will go around in circles until you provide an MRE as requested by @Patsytalk in the very first comment.
